# Does a charged particle propagating in free space have a 'self-energy' like term due to it’s interaction with the fluctuations of the quantum vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, self-energy

Does a charged particle propagating in free space have a 'self-energy' like term due to it’s interaction with the fluctuations of the quantum vacuum? (particle-antiparticle pairs popping into and out of existence)

Or is it the case the the fluctuations of the quantum vacuum don't exist long enough (from the uncertainty principle in order to conserve energy) for the electron to 'notice' them.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. The self-energy term in QFT is the 1PI contribution to the Dyson resummed propagator, I don't know why you are talking about "fluctuations of the quantum vacuum" or the uncertainty principle.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for your reply. 
Fluctuations of the quantum vacuum - particle-antiparticle pairs  popping into and out of existence. Presumably they have some influence on the surrounding space, due to their charge which an electron in said space would feel. So I don't mean literally self energy, that's why I said self energy like term, I mean some contribution that would need to be taken into account.

Comment: @ACuriousMind. If you could help me formulate the question in a better phrasing I would appreciate that help too! Thanks

Comment: Particles don't "pop in and out of existence". That's a literal interpretation of certain Feynman diagrams for which there is no basis in the formalism. The self-energy term in the resummed propagator comes from 1PI diagrams, if you want to call that "fluctuations of the quantum vacuum", fine, but I don't understand what your *question* about that is.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think the Op refers to the attitude that virtual particles don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to think of a free on-shell particle as a mode that propagates like a soliton far from interactions then you can think of it as a thing that interacts with the vacuum so as to make more of itself.

But really you should stick to asking questions the formalism is designed to answer.

The vacuum is not a thing like a house that provides space for particles to appear and disappear. And if it were it doesn't stand there with a stopwatch enforcing an uncertainty principle.

What you have is a single electron-positron field whose modes encompess every possible allowed way of having any number of electrons and/or positrons. And this single field has values at every point in space and the values aren't real numbers (or complex numbers or vectors) they are operators.

And there is a different field for photons and another for neutrinos and another for W and another for Z and one for all the up quarks and ones for all the other quarks and they include the modes for the antiparticles as well and there is one for the gluons.

And the vacuum isn't a separate thing. It is just a state with fewer electrons and such. So few that the mathematical operations that normally remove electrons instead act on the vacuum as if you just didn't act with a mathematical operation at all (and I don't mean doing nothing, I mean as if you didn't use any operation, or you can just think it gives zero but that doesn't mean it gives the vacuum the vacuum and zero are different).

So the vacuum is just a state of the field like other states it isn't a separate thing. You describe states of having electrons by having a mathematical operation act on the vacuum

So having something act again would be redundant, the whole idea is confused. It would be like if we defined cookies as taking flour and sugar and cooking them (a bit of an over simplification) for 10 minutes. And then you asked if we need to say how cookies interact with flour and sugar and heat. Cookies are a state of flour and sugar.

An electron isn't distinct from a vacuum. The vacuum state is one possible state of the electron-positron field and the state of one electron is another and the state of two electrons is another state. They are all states of the field. So you never have a vacuum and an electron (well, there are states that are superpositions of states with different numbers of electrons).

But the point is the state of having an electron is already a modification of the vacuum state, making a different modification would just be not having that state of the electron.

Comment: Thanks for your in depth answer. I fear you've misunderstood me and it's my fault because my question isn't well written.
In the QFT framework the electron is a perturbation of the fields away from their ground state, the uncertainty principle says that we always have some uncertainty in the energy at a give spot over a given time scale. This fact leads to the creation of virtual particle pairs that quickly annihilate, quickly being the keyword. My question is basically - What effect, if any, do they have on the electron as it propagates?

Comment: @Dan I think I disagree. A virtual particle is simply a line a diagram designed to remind you which limits to take as you sum over a bunch of energy momentum for a certain number of vertex factors in a certain order of a perturbative expansion. They aren't actually particles.

Comment: I don't think they are real either, my understanding is that they are a mathematical tool used to calculate real results but that they are non physical (like the wavefunction or imaginary numbers). The fluctuations of the ground state are real though, right? [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation). So they [the fluctuations] must have some influence on the environment perceived by the electron

Comment: Imaginary numbers are just used to encode a rotation, they're an abstract mathematical concept used to calculate the result of a physical process. You can't have _i_ amount of apples and you can't have an _i_ sided shape. I am aware there is some reason to suspect the physicality of the wfn. To your point -  What effect (if any) does the presence of fluctuations in the field have on a pertubation (electron) propagating through that field? Analogy - A wave in a still pond behaves differently to a wave in a rough sea, an electron in free space is the latter, is this accounted for and how?

Comment: @Dan I can't tell if you have a typo. Are you claiming that the only option for imaginary numbers are as abstract mathematical objects? That is a tough claim to substantiate because one person that makes a realistic model that is algebraically isomorphic proves you wrong? There are objects and transformations and some transformations when you do them twice are the same as the transformation of multiplying by -1. Your objections could be used to claim vectors are abstract since you can't have a shape with a vector number of sides or have a vector many apples.

Comment: @Dan As for the rough sea versus a still pond. What are the two things you want to compare? I don't see two things on your question or in your comment. That's why I point out there aren't two states one with virtual particles and one without.